# JQGRID Set attributes to dropdownlist different from id and value/text

Tags: jquery, json, drop-down-menu, jqgrid

This is a piece of my code:

```
colModel: [{ name: 'Cuenta', index: 'Cuenta_Id', width: 0, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: {value: jqGridCargarArregloDatosDropDown() }}
```

The "jqGridCargarArregloDatosDropDown()" function retrieves this json data:

```
"Id:Texto;Id2:Texto2;Id3:Texto3;"
```

I need to set, for example, the "name" attribute of my dropdownlist option tag too like this:

```
<select>
<option value="Id" name="....">Texto</option>
<option value="Id2" name="....">Texto2</option>
</select>
```

Anybody knows how to achieve this using json as a datasource for the dropdownlist?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to data from database so you can directly take url of data fetching for dropdownlist like this ..

```
editoptions: {dataUrl: project + '/Handler/ddlHandler.ashx',buildSelect:true }
```

and take **buildSelect**  to take true because it convert json or xml to normal  format.

please check this link for help

```
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editable
```

---

You should be use like this

```
colModel: [{ name: 'Cuenta', index: 'Cuenta_Id', width: 0, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: '/', buildSelect: new Function('return jqGridCargarArregloDatosDropDown()')value:  }}
```

and always remember jqGridCargarArregloDatosDropDown() function return value in form of below string

```
<select><option value='1'>One</option>…</select>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer man, should i define "new Function()" case i wrote what you said and i didnt work. i wrote this in the column definition :  { name: 'Cuenta', index: 'Cuenta_Id', width: 0, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { dataUrl: '/', buildSelect: new Function('return jqGridCargarArregloDatosDropDown()') }} and the string returned from jqGridCargarArregloDatosDropDown() is : <select><option value='1'>One</option></select>

Comment: also i don't have an html that throws the "<select><option value='1'>One</option>…</select>" string, i just have a variable with the string.

Comment: i need to set it this way cause i need to add attributes to the option tag dynamically from database